# XSLT: How to output localized data only?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, localization, xquery

Given the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xsl"?>
<Document>
  <Translations>
    <Translation name="Resource">Invariant Resource</Translation>
    <Translation name="Resource" lang="en">English Resource</Translation>
    <Translation name="Resource" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Resource</Translation>
    <Translation name="Resource" lang="en-GB">British English Resource</Translation>
    <Translation name="Message">Invariant Message</Translation>
    <Translation name="Message" lang="en">English Message</Translation>
    <Translation name="Message" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Message</Translation>
    <Translation name="Message" lang="en-AU">Australian English Message</Translation>
  </Translations>
</Document>
```

I need to select a set of Translation elements such that the set contains unique values for the "name" attribute, and the "best match" for a given locale ('en-US', 'es-MX', 'fr', etc.).  When I say best match, I would like to first look for an element with the full matching locale, then look for a match based on just the first two characters, then look for an element with no lang specified.

For example, if I pass in a locale of 'en-CA' when transforming the above data, I would like to get the following two elements:

```xml
<Translation name="Resource" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Resource</Translation>
<Translation name="Message" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Message</Translation>
```

But if I pass in 'en-GB', I would like to get:

```xml
<Translation name="Resource" lang="en-GB">British English Resource</Translation>
<Translation name="Message" lang="en">English Message</Translation>
```

And finally if I pass in a value such as 'es' or 'es-MX', I would expect to get:

```xml
<Translation name="Resource">Invariant Resource</Translation>
<Translation name="Message">Invariant Message</Translation>
```

I'm extremely new to XSLT, but I think I have something that works.  I just need to know if there is a better way to do it (simpler, more elegant, more performant, etc.)

Here's my first stab at it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key match="Translation" name="TranslationName" use="concat(@name,':',@lang)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- locale parameter for translation -->
    <xsl:param name="locale"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="Document/Translations/Translation[@lang=$locale or @lang=substring($locale,1,2) or not(@lang)]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@lang=$locale and count(key('TranslationName', concat(@name,':',$locale)))=1">
          <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@lang=substring($locale,1,2) and count(key('TranslationName', concat(@name,':',$locale)))=0">
          <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(@lang) and count(key('TranslationName', concat(@name,':',$locale))|key('TranslationName', concat(@name,':',substring($locale,1,2))))=0">
          <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my first time to post a question, so please let me know if I need to add/edit/remove anything.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a good first question.

Comment: note, that your xsl for `en-AU` set on a file with only `en-CA`, `en-GB` and no `en` will not produce output. My answer, hopefully corrects this also. After all, they _can_ understand each other if they really try, no?

Comment: While I agree, the should be able to understand each other, my requirements are very clear about how they want the language fallback to work.  But thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you could use msxsl:node-set or the like, you might do it like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="locale" select="'en-AU'"/>
<!-- locale parameter for translation -->
    <xsl:variable name="sorted">
        <xsl:for-each select="Document/Translations/Translation">
            <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            <xsl:sort select="not(@lang=$locale)"/>
            <xsl:sort select="not(starts-with(@lang, substring($locale,1,2)))"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@lang"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($sorted)/*">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or @name!=preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

P.S. This one might work on standard 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="locale" select="'en-AU'"/>
<!-- locale parameter for translation -->
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="Document/Translations/Translation"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$path">
        <xsl:variable name="curName" select="$path[@name=current()/@name]"/>
        <xsl:if test="count($curName[1] | .)=1">
            <xsl:for-each select="$curName">
            <xsl:sort select="not(@lang=$locale)"/>
            <xsl:sort select="not(starts-with(@lang, substring($locale,1,2)))"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@lang"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

P.P.S. If you don't want to sort you might just do the filtering (preserves document order). Also, different grouping mechanism:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="locale" select="'en'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="locale-lang" select="substring($locale,1,2)"/>
<!-- locale parameter for translation -->
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="Document/Translations/Translation"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$path[not(preceding-sibling::Translation/@name=@name)]">
        <xsl:variable name="curName" select="$path[@name=current()/@name]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="test1" select="$curName[@lang=$locale]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="test2" select="$curName[@lang=$locale-lang]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="test3" select="$curName[starts-with(@lang, $locale-lang)]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="test4" select="$curName[not(@lang)]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$test1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$test1[1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$test2">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$test2[1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$test3">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$test3[1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$test4">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$test4[1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: These are all great!  Right now, I think I may use a hybrid approach with pieces from each.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This short and simple transformation (no variables, `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`, `xsl:if`, xsl:sort, `xsl:element`)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pCode" select="'en-GB'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTransName" match="@name" use="."/>

 <xsl:key name="Resource" match="Translation[@name='Resource']"
          use="@lang"/>
 <xsl:key name="Message" match="Translation[@name='Message']"
          use="@lang"/>
 <xsl:key name="Resource" match="Translation[@name='Resource']"
                          use="boolean(@lang)"/>
 <xsl:key name="Message" match="Translation[@name='Message']"
                          use="boolean(@lang)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select=
   "/*/*/*/@name[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kTransName', .)[1])]">
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       "key(., $pCode)
       |
        key(., substring($pCode, 1, 2))
          [not(key(current(), $pCode))]
       |
        key(., 'false')
          [not(key(current(), $pCode)
              |
               key(current(), substring($pCode, 1, 2))
              )
          ]
       "/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Document>
    <Translations>
        <Translation name="Resource">Invariant Resource</Translation>
        <Translation name="Resource" lang="en">English Resource</Translation>
        <Translation name="Resource" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Resource</Translation>
        <Translation name="Resource" lang="en-GB">British English Resource</Translation>
        <Translation name="Message">Invariant Message</Translation>
        <Translation name="Message" lang="en">English Message</Translation>
        <Translation name="Message" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Message</Translation>
        <Translation name="Message" lang="en-AU">Australian English Message</Translation>
    </Translations>
</Document>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Translation name="Resource" lang="en-GB">British English Resource</Translation>
<Translation name="Message" lang="en">English Message</Translation>
```

**If we change the global/external parameter to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pCode" select="'en-CA'"/>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
<Translation name="Resource" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Resource</Translation>
<Translation name="Message" lang="en-CA">Canadian English Message</Translation>
```

**If we change the global/external parameter to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pCode" select="'es-MX'"/>
```

**again the wanted result is produced**:

```
<Translation name="Resource">Invariant Resource</Translation>
<Translation name="Message">Invariant Message</Translation>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately there will be many more possible values for @name other than just "Resource" and "Message".  I guess I should have made that a little more clear in the question.